# Encode Base64 data from Clipboard Image

Tags: vba, excel

I can get the Base64 data from a `CommandBarButton.Picture` by copying it to the Windows Clipboard and saving it to file.

Unfortunately, this process is too slow.  It takes about 45 seconds to process the 4676 unique images.  Is there a way to get the Base64 data directly from an image in the Windows Clipboard?

Alternately, is there a way to Multithread the process?  I am working on running a PowerShell script that will process the clipboard but would rather do it directly from the VBA.

```
Option Explicit
'Referrence: Stephen Bullen: http://www.oaltd.co.uk
'Open the clipboard to read
Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
'Get a pointer to the bitmap/metafile
Private Declare Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Integer) As Long
'Close the clipboard
Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
'Convert the handle into an OLE IPicture interface.
Private Declare Function OleCreatePictureIndirect Lib "olepro32.dll" (PicDesc As uPicDesc, RefIID As GUID, ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As Long, IPic As IPicture) As Long
'Declare a UDT to store a GUID for the IPicture OLE Interface
Private Type GUID: Data1 As Long: Data2 As Integer: Data3 As Integer: Data4(0 To 7) As Byte: End Type
'Declare a UDT to store the bitmap information
Private Type uPicDesc: Size As Long: Type As Long: hPic As Long: hPal As Long: End Type
Private Declare Function GetObject Lib "gdi32" Alias "GetObjectA" (ByVal hObject As Long, ByVal nCount As Long, lpObject As Any) As Long
Private Declare Function GetBitmapBits Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hBitmap As Long, ByVal dwCount As Long, lpBits As Any) As Long

Private Type Bitmap
    bmType As Long
    bmWidth As Long
    bmHeight As Long
    bmWidthBytes As Long
    bmPlanes As Integer
    bmBitsPixel As Integer
    bmBits As Long
End Type

Public Sub SavePictureFromClipBoard(ImagePath As String)

    Dim IPic As IPicture

    OpenClipboard 0&

    OleCreatePictureIndirect getuPicInfo, getIID_IDispatch, True, IPic

    SavePicture IPic, ImagePath

    CloseClipboard

    Set IPic = Nothing

End Sub

Private Function getIID_IDispatch() As GUID
    Dim IID_IDispatch As GUID
    With IID_IDispatch
        .Data1 = &H7BF80980
        .Data2 = &HBF32
        .Data3 = &H101A:
        .Data4(0) = &H8B
        .Data4(1) = &HBB
        .Data4(2) = &H0
        .Data4(3) = &HAA
        .Data4(4) = &H0
        .Data4(5) = &H30
        .Data4(6) = &HC
        .Data4(7) = &HAB
    End With
    getIID_IDispatch = IID_IDispatch
End Function

Private Function getuPicInfo() As uPicDesc
    Const PICTYPE_BITMAP = 1
    Dim uPicInfo As uPicDesc

    ' Fill uPicInfo with necessary parts.
    With uPicInfo
        .Size = Len(uPicInfo)                         ' Length of structure.
        .Type = PICTYPE_BITMAP                        ' Type of Picture
        .hPic = GetClipboardData(xlBitmap)            ' Handle to image.
        .hPal = xlBitmap                              ' Handle to palette (if bitmap).
    End With
    getuPicInfo = uPicInfo
End Function

Public Function getADODBStream(ImagePath As String) As Byte()
    Const adTypeBinary = 1
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Type = adTypeBinary
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile (ImagePath)
        getADODBStream = .Read()
    End With
End Function

Public Function getBase64FromImageFile(ImagePath As String) As String
    With CreateObject("MSXml2.DOMDocument")
        With .createElement("Base64Data")
            .DataType = "bin.base64"
            .nodeTypedValue = getADODBStream(ImagePath)
            getBase64FromImageFile = .Text
        End With
    End With
End Function

Public Function getBase64FromByteArray(Bytes() As Byte) As String
    With CreateObject("MSXml2.DOMDocument")
        With .createElement("Base64Data")
            .DataType = "bin.base64"
            .nodeTypedValue = Bytes
            getBase64FromByteArray = .Text
        End With
    End With
End Function

Public Function getBytes(Picture1 As IPictureDisp) As Byte()
    Dim PicBits() As Byte, PicInfo As Bitmap

    GetObject Picture1, Len(PicInfo), PicInfo

    ReDim PicBits((PicInfo.bmWidth * PicInfo.bmHeight * 3) - 1) As Byte

    GetBitmapBits Picture1, UBound(PicBits), PicBits(0)

    getBytes = PicBits()
End Function
```

### Addendum

I am able to read the Byte() from the both the CommandBarButton and the ClipBoard Image. The problem I have i that the Bitmap has a Picture Byte(0 to 767) and a Mask Byte(0 to 767) that combine to form a complete Image.  Note:  the Mask is sort of background Image that determines the pixel intensity of the Picture. The SavePicture function seems to merge the two parts.  The ADODB.Stream saved file returns a Byte(0 to 821).

When copied to the ClipBoard, the Byte() arrays both the ClipBoard IPicture and CommandBarButton Picture are identical.

[image: Bitmap Images]

The three Images above are the CommandBarButton Picture, CommandBarButton Mask, and the Clipboard Image saved to file and then loaded into Image controls.

I am perplexed on how the two Byte() are combined and how the colors are derived from them.

Comment: Multi-threading in VBA? LOL!

Comment: @rory.ap The idea is not so much to multithread the vba as to pass some of the  workload to another application/language.

Comment: Just a thought, but would it be possible to read the pointer of the picture, then read the bytes from there?

Comment: @RyanWildry Yes, it is.  I added more details to my post.  Thank you for you comments.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your code, it could be handy one day.  I am going to look into this further but I'm not sure you're going to be able to speed it up without starting over with in different direction, but I'm curious, **how often are you running this that qualifies < 1/100th of a second per image as "too slow"?**    Not sure if you're aware, images are stored on the clipboard as a bitmaps (no Base64 involved there), which are pretty much the "least efficient" method there is.  Base64 isn't far off (which is why images take more space after conversion to Base64.)

Comment: I could just do a first-time preload and everything would run smooth but I wanted to see if I could cut the time down.  The problem is that there are roughly 23000 valid Face ideas with only 8800ish icons of which only 4676 are unique.  For the first thousand or so t runs smooth but they have several 100+ clumps (even a 4000+ clump) of blank icons that slow things down.  I made a PowerShell script that can extract the base64 data but I won't run properly from Excel.  I was thnking about having it load the pictures in the background.

Comment: The end game is to make this: [Office CommandBarButton Icon Browser in the VBEditor](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/194521/office-commandbarbutton-icon-browser-in-the-vbeditor)  into a complete menu Editor.  Extracting the base64 data will allow me to write HTML to a Web Browser control.  I want to be able to drag and drag copy items between list and repositioning them by dragging them.