How to Get image bytes directly out of clipboard
I am writing a script to automatically calculate totals for each category from a report that is exported to an excel spreadsheet. The system that generates the report uses images (for some reason) in the spreadsheets it exports to identify each of the possible states for the category instead of putting the information in a cell as value.

The system does not generate the report with alt-text information on each image, and it also does not have unique names for each image to help identifying what the image is. The solution I am trying to implement is to copy the picture and get the bytes directly from the clipboard into a byte array so that I can associate byte patterns with specific images.

The system that generates the reports was not designed with JAWS users (blind users) in mind. Instead of getting descriptions of the images, users get something along the lines of "image 1, image 2, image 3, etc..." JAWS relies on alt-text to describe stuff on the screen to users. The sheet is used by both sighted people, and non-sighted people.


Public Sub getImageBytes()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim shp As shape
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
    
    
    For Each shp In ws.Shapes
        shp.CopyPicture
    Next shp
End Sub


Attempt #1:
I attempted to use the GetFromClipboard method in the learn.microsoft VBA documentation.
Issue #1, I get a FORMATETC error because the getText function is only designed to work with text data.
**Attempt #2: **
I was able to get a working prototype working by using the method described in this Microsoft Forum, but it works by first using powerpoint to paste the image into a slide, then export the slide to a png file, and from there I was able to read the bytes from the PNG file into a byte array and determine the image pattern from there. The issue however, is that this method takes forever and isn't very efficient. Also each report could contain 10s of thousands of shape images. About 5 of these reports are ran per week. I am concerned that writing and deleting 10s of thousands if not hundreds of thousands of images daily to a harddrive will reduce the lifespan of that harddrive over the course of a year, especially if the harddrive is a solid state.
Issue #1, it takes too long. The work has been done in less time by a human than the initial test with this method was able to do because of how long the writing and reading process took.
Solution #1, I would like to get the same work done entirely within the ram by getting the copied image bytes directly out of the clipboard.
Attempt #3:
I have also attempted using a solution found on this VBForums thread, but I kept getting an error saying the datatype FORMATETC could not be found.

Does this answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79092196/getting-macro-error-pastespecial-of-object-worksheet-failed-while-pasting-f ?

This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50370223/encode-base64-data-from-clipboard-image might have the bones of what you want, but still writes a copy of the clipboard data to disk...

Unfortunately Michal, your suggestion would not answer my question because I don't need to paste the image after copying it. I need to get the bytes directly out of the clipboard and clear the clipboard after.

Tim, I actually looked at it again, and I noticed the SavePictureFromClipboard subroutine uses an IPicture to store the data before saving it to a file. I don't know why I didn't see it before. I will try this first thing tomorrow!

I attempted to use the code shown in your link, Tim, and it partially works. However, the function getBytes() in the example doesn't work. I either get a variable type mismatch error or an automation error, and Excel and the editor crash if I attempt to use debug.
Also, I could not do anything with the IPicture variable "IPic" in the function SavePictureFromClipBoard except save it to a PNG file.
I can get the handle/memory address pointer for the location where the copied image is stored. Is it possible to get the image bytes from the handle without saving as in the example linked?

I have to admit I've done very little with win API/clipboard programming: I just find already-worked-out code and at the most make some minor mods...   On another tack though - have you tried unzipping a copy of one of your reports and see if you can id the images in that structure?   For example does it have one image copy for each unique picture in /xl/media, or one copy for each individual shape?  You might have more luck from that direction...

Have you looked at Stephen Bullen's PastePicture routine? A 32/64bit version of it is available: https://github.com/KallunWillock/JustMoreVBA/blob/main/Images/modImages_PastePicture.bas
It all depends on the clipboard format that you're storing the image, and if you're using the CopyPicture method, whether you opt for the Picture or Bitmap options.

Unfortunately Tim, I am constrained by the information contained within the exported Excel spreadsheet.
Dan, thank you for the suggestion. The code examples in the link you provided look promising. I will try working with this example as soon as possible.

I have made significant progress. I am reading bytes from a pointer in memory now. The only issue I am having is 1 - I can't figure out how to limit the number of bytes to read to the actual size of the block allocated to the information stored at the pointer. 2, the bytes I am getting are inconsistent even though I am locking the memory block for reading until the bytes have been read into an array and using the pointer given by the clipboard. I will post an update once I get something working. I have to piece together stuff from all of the links and other references that have been given.

If you have a code repository submitted to GitHub, I'd be happy to help you improve it.

Thank you, but I have sidelined this project for now because I seem to be at an impasse with the documentation that Microsoft currently has available. I can write the bytes to a png file and read the bytes out of the png file, so for now that will have to do. Unfortunately, it isn't logistically feasible at the moment to pursue it because I have something that does work-ish, based on the previously answered questions. Thank you all.
